# XSS and other ways to terminate JavaScript strings

Tags: javascript, string, xss

Is there a different way to terminate strings in JavaScript?

I'm testing a server for XSS vulnerabilities, and I'm seeing the following code in the HTTP response:

```
<script>
var myVar = "USER CONTROLLED STRING";
</script>
```

The user-controlled string comes from the URL and all double quotes are removed before the response is generated.  Besides that, all other characters are allowed.

Is XSS possible?

(And ,yes, I know the proper thing to do here would would hex encode(\xHH) all non-alphanumeric characters as per recommended by the [OWASP XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.233_-_JavaScript_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_JavaScript_Data_Values), but from I tester's perspective I want to know if I could exploit this.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can perform an attack: http://jsfiddle.net/vTmq6/1/

```
<script>
var myVar = "</script><script>alert('hacked');</script>";
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

A `</script>` would denote the *script* [element’s end tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#end-tags) regardless of whether the resulting JavaScript code is valid or not. This is due to the [restrictions on the contents of raw text elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#cdata-rcdata-restrictions), which the *script* element belongs to:

> The text in [raw text](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#raw-text-elements) and [RCDATA elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#rcdata-elements) must not contain any occurrences of the string "`</`" (U+003C LESS-THAN SIGN, U+002F SOLIDUS) followed by characters that case-insensitively match the tag name of the element followed by one of "tab" (U+0009), "LF" (U+000A), "FF" (U+000C), "CR" (U+000D), U+0020 SPACE, "`>`" (U+003E), or "`/`" (U+002F).